# Show this function series converge uniformly to a derivative function on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

We define $f_n(x) = \frac{n x^2 \sin(nx)}{n^4 + x^4}$. We have to prove that $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n $$ converges uniformly to a derivative function on $\mathbb{R}$. To prove that, it suffices to show that there exists $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x_0)$ converges (just take $x_0 = 0$) and that $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n'$$ converges uniformly to a certain function on $\mathbb{R}$. If we do the derivative, we obtain $$ f_n'(x) = \frac{(2nx \sin(nx) + n^2x^2 \cos(nx))(n^4+x^4) - 4nx^5 \sin(nx)}{(n^4+x^4)^2}. $$ Now, to show the uniform convergence of the series, I think we must use the Weierstrass criterion, but I don't know how to obtain an upper bound valid on $\mathbb{R}$ for $f_n'$.

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: You do not need to find an upper bound on *all* of $\mathbb R$. It is sufficient to find bounds $M_n(a)$ on each $[0,a]$, $a>0$, for $f_n'$  such that the sum of these bounds converges. That is straightforward: Estimate $\sin,\cos$ by 1, $x$ by $a$ in the numerator, $x$ by 0 in the denominator.

Comment: Yes, that was my first idea, but I wasn't very sure that uniform convergence in every compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ implies uniform convergence on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Use the local uniform convergence to prove the differentiability, then extend this to the whole axis.

Comment: I see that the series would converge uniformly on every compact set of the real line to a derivative function on $\mathbb{R}$, but how can I prove that I have uniform convergence on the whole real line?

Comment: @JavierGonzález Robert Z did not prove uniform convergence on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: No, extend the differentiability, not the uniform convergence.

Comment: @JavierGonzález Are you interested in the uniform convergence of $\sum f_n$ on the whole real line or in the differentiability of its limit?

Comment: Both. I need to prove that it converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$ to a derivatite function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ in $\mathbb{R}$: note that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)=x^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n \sin(nx)}{n^4 + x^4}$$
and $\left|\frac{n\sin(nx)}{n^4 + x^4}\right|\leq \frac{1}{n^3}$, then by the $M$-test the series converges uniformly in $\mathbb{R}$ to some continuous function $F$.

2) As regards the differentiability of $F$, all you need is the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n'$ in the compact set $[-R,R]$ for all $R>0$: for $x\in [-R,R]$, and for $n\geq1$,
$$|f'_n(x)|\leq  \frac{(2nR + n^2R^2)(n^4+R^4) + 4nR^5}{n^8}\leq  \frac{C_R}{n^2}$$
for some constant $C_R$ (which depends on $R$). Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ converges uniformly to the derivative of $F$ on $[-R,R]$ for all $R>|x_0|$ (recall that differentiability is a **local property**).

Comment: How do you prove it?

Comment: @JavierGonzález See my edit.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy OP is asking for uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ in $\mathbb{R}$ AND that the limit function is differentiable (not necessarily  the  uniform convergence of  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f'_n$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy "Uniform convergence is asserted on the whole line" for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ not for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n'$!

Comment: @RobertZ You are right as far the question is concerned. But OP has given an argument and he wants some help with in completing it. He has asserted that the differentiated series also converges uniformly.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy   I think OP changed his mind because he accepted my answer.

Comment: @RobertZ I have deleted my first comment.

Comment: @RobertZ No, sir. I did not downvote your answer. Just wanted to make  a comment.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you for your time.